# API Error 422 while calling a FastAPI api that uses a pydantic model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

These are the Pydantic models involved in the problem:

```
class DishBase(BaseModel):
    d_name: constr(min_length=1)
    d_i_names: conlist(item_type=str, min_items=1)


class DishCreate(DishBase):
    d_i_weights: conlist(item_type=confloat(gt=0, lt=1), min_items=1)
    d_f_names: conlist(item_type=str, min_items=1)
    d_f_values: conlist(item_type=Union[bool, int, str, float], min_items=1)

    @validator("d_i_weights")
    def num_ingrs_must_match_num_weights(cls, v, values):
        if "d_i_names" in values and len(v) != len(values["d_i_names"]):
            raise ValueError("The number of ingredients and weights must match")
        return v

    @validator("d_i_weights")
    def weights_must_add_up_to_1(cls, v):
        if sum(v) != 1:
            raise ValueError("Weights must add up to 1")
        return v

    @validator("d_f_values")
    def num_feat_must_match_num_values(cls, v, values):
        if "d_f_names" in values and len(v) != len(values["d_f_names"]):
            raise ValueError("The number of features and values must match")
        return v

    @validator("d_f_values")
    def type_feat_values_must_match_with_db(cls, v, values):
        for index, feature_name in enumerate(values["d_f_names"]):
            conn, cursor = get_db()
            query = """SELECT * FROM features WHERE f_name = %s;"""
            value = (feature_name,)
            cursor.execute(query, value)
            row = dict(cursor.fetchone())
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            feature_type = row["f_type"]
            if type(v[index]) != feature_type:
                raise ValueError(f"type of feature {feature_name} is {feature_type}, but 
                {type(v[index])} is provided")
```

When I make a call to the API:

```
@router.post("/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=schemas.DishResponse)
def create_dish(dish: schemas.DishCreate):
    conn, cursor = get_db()
    query = """SELECT * FROM dishes WHERE d_name = %s;"""
    value = (dish.d_name,)
    cursor.execute(query, value)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    if row != None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail=f"This 
        dish already exists")

    conn, cursor = get_db()
    query = """INSERT INTO dishes (d_name) VALUES (%s) RETURNING *;"""
    value = (dish.d_name,)
    cursor.execute(query, value)
    new_dish = dict(cursor.fetchone())
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    dish_id = new_dish["d_id"]

    for ingredient in dish.d_i_names:
        conn, cursor = get_db()
        query = """SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE i_name = %s;"""
        value = (ingredient,)
        cursor.execute(query, value)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        if row == None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"ingredient 
            {ingredient} was not found")

    for index, ingredient in enumerate(dish.d_i_names):
        conn, cursor = get_db()
        query = """SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE i_name = %s;"""
        value = (ingredient,)
        cursor.execute(query, value)
        row = dict(cursor.fetchone())
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        ingredient_id = row["i_id"]

        conn, cursor = get_db()
        query = """INSERT INTO dishes_ingredients (di_d_id, di_i_id, di_i_weight) VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s);"""
        values = (dish_id, ingredient_id, dish.d_i_weights[index])
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    for feature in dish.d_f_names:
        conn, cursor = get_db()
        query = """SELECT * FROM features WHERE f_name = %s;"""
        value = (feature,)
        cursor.execute(query, value)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        if row == None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"feature 
            {feature} was not found")

    for index, feature in enumerate(dish.d_f_names):
        conn, cursor = get_db()
        query = """SELECT * FROM features WHERE f_name = %s;"""
        value = (feature,)
        cursor.execute(query, value)
        row = dict(cursor.fetchone())
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        feature_id = row["f_id"]

        conn, cursor = get_db()
        query = """INSERT INTO dishes_features (df_d_id, df_f_id, df_f_value) VALUES (%s, 
        %s, %s);"""
        values = (dish_id, feature_id, str(dish.d_f_values[index]))
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    return dish
```

with a body request:

```
{
  "d_name": "papa dish",
  "d_i_names": ["ingredient 1", "ingredient 2"],
  "d_i_weights": [0.3, 0.7],
  "d_f_names": ["feature A", "feature B", "feature C", "feature D"],
  "d_f_values": [True, 3, "fatty", 4.5]
}
```

I get a 422 error with the following detail:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        191
      ],
      "msg": "Expecting value: line 6 column 18 (char 191)",
      "type": "value_error.jsondecode",
      "ctx": {
        "msg": "Expecting value",
        "doc": "{\n  \"d_name\": \"papa dish\",\n  \"d_i_names\": [\"ingredient 1\", \"ingredient 2\"],\n  \"d_i_weights\": [0.3, 0.7],\n  \"d_f_names\": [\"feature A\", \"feature B\", \"feature C\", \"feature D\"],\n  \"d_f_values\": [True, 3, \"fatty\", 4.5]\n}",
        "pos": 191,
        "lineno": 6,
        "colno": 18
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is in the boolean value of "d_f_values". When I remove the boolean from the list, I get a succesful response. I don't understand why this happen. I would really appreciate any help.

Update:  I have just found that, although d_f_values are provided in the body of the request, the API parses the value of that field to None. Why?

Comment: I have also tried unsuccesfully this.

Answer (score 0):

in schema **DishCreate** try this

```
d_f_values: List = None
```

it's mean if you have a value it will be in list if not then it will be None.

Comment: Hi Tanveer. I have tried this and I get the exact same error.

Comment: List will import from typing import List

Comment: I know. I did it in that way. But unfortunately no change